# AngularJS Setting the active option of a select element to the value of a different angular object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have researched this issue and have found solutions using php but not angular.

One of the requirements for saving the data on my page requires that two seperate angular objects have the same Id. Below is the code:

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="temp" ng-options="type as type.Name for type in Displays">
</select>
```

AngularJS

```
$scope.Prop = Prop.data;
$scope.Displays = Displays.data;
```

What I would like to do is when the angular object is selected in the dropdown I want to assign the Displays.Id to equal the Prop.TestTemplateId.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be ng-change

View:

```
<select class="form-control"  
        ng-options="type as type.Name for type in Displays"
        ng-change="setId(type.Id)">
</select>
```

Ctrl:

```
$scope.setId = function(Id){
    $scope.Prop.TestTemplateId = Id;
};
```

Or you can just set the value directly in the view

```
<select class="form-control"  
        ng-options="type as type.Name for type in Displays"
        ng-change="Prop.TestTemplateId = type.Id;">
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the value you select in your dropdownbox is bound to '$scope.temp'. Therefore, when initializing the controller, you could watch that variable and update '$scope.testProp.TestTemplateId' with the new value as follows:

```
$scope.$watch('temp', function(newType, oldType) {
    $scope.Prop.TestTemplateId = newType.Id;
});
```

This will make ..

- angular watch '$scope.temp'
- whenever that value changes (e.g. selected via dropdown), the given function will be called with the new value (and the old value)
- within that function you can update '$scope.testProp.TestTemplateId'

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive on the `<select>` the would trigger a function that sets/updates the value of the property. You can retrieve the value of selected item from the "temp" property you defined in the ngModel directive.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="temp" ng-options="type as type.Name for type in Displays" ng-change="update()">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    // can retrieve value of selected item of "temp" ngModel property
    $scope.Prop.TestTemplateId = $scope.temp.id;
};
```